# How to check net Info in React Native iOS?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

**I need to check Internet connection in react native iOS**

I would try following code:

```
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
   console.log(isConnected);
});
```

that can work fine in react native android application,
But it always return 'false' in react native iOS .

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is currently an open issue about this in [react native's github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8615).

You can see the discussion there, but in short - the `fetch` is always returning `false`, but you can work around it by listening to the connection changed event.

**Code example from there:**

```
componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this.handleConnectionChange);

    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done(
      (isConnected) => { this.setState({ status: isConnected }); }
    );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('change', this.handleConnectionChange);
}

handleConnectionChange = (isConnected) => {
        this.setState({ status: isConnected });
        console.log(`is connected: ${this.state.status}`);
}
```

**Edit:**

Seems like this issue has been [worked on](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/dbafc29).
Also, `change` event was renamed to `connectionChange`. Updated workaround code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectionChange);

    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done(
      (isConnected) => { this.setState({ status: isConnected }); }
    );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectionChange);
}

handleConnectionChange = (isConnected) => {
        this.setState({ status: isConnected });
        console.log(`is connected: ${this.state.status}`);
}
```

**Updated:**

The `change` event type is deprecated. Consider using the `connectionChange` event type.

Comment: This might be very late. but.....NetInfo's "change" event is deprecated. Listen to the "connectionChange" event instead.

Comment: this approach causes a warning if the isConnected.fetch promise is resolved after the component is unmounted, due to calling setState on an unmounted component

Answer (score 0):

By using [this](https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo) module you can subscribe to network state updates

```
const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});
```

and also you can find if the internet is reachable with the currently active network connection.

```
console.log("Is Internet Reachable?", state.isInternetReachable);
```

I also explained usage of react-native-netinfo and its features [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26dk9cLfgfU) with source code.