# NetInfo in react native not working in ios

Tags: react-native

I have used NetInfo in react native in Android it's work fine but in ios when i run in simulator it's shows always internet is offline.Later in found Asynchronously check internet Connection in both ios and android platform but i can't get correct example please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**For ios You have to add following things :**

*1. Import netinfo :*

```
import {NetInfo} from 'react-native';
```

*2. Add Listener :*

```
componentDidMount() {
  NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this.handleConnectionChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('change', this.handleConnectionChange);
}

handleConnectionChange = (isConnected) => {
    console.log(isConnected);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF THIS DOESN'T WORK ......

import {NetInfo} from 'react-native';

```
     NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {

      if(isConnected)
           {
                console.log('Your are connected....')
            }

            else
            {
                console.log('Your are disconnected....')
            }

        })
```

this may help.....
[How to check net Info in React Native iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198978/how-to-check-net-info-in-react-native-ios)

Comment: For iOS:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198978/how-to-check-net-info-in-react-native-ios