# react-native ios netInfo behaving strange

Tags: ios, react-native

in android 'connectionChange' event is fired only when the device comes online from offline or vice-versa but in IOS it is calling everytime. 
any workaround for this?

```
componentWillMount(){
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
        if (isConnected) {
            this.setState({
                netConnection: isConnected
            });
        } else {
            ToastAndroid.show("Connection TimeOut!", ToastAndroid.LONG);
            this.setState({
                netConnection: isConnected
            });
        }
    });

    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
        "connectionChange",
        this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
    );
}

componentWillUnmount(){
     NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
            "connectionChange",
            this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
        );
}

handleFirstConnectivityChange = (isConnected)=>{
if (isConnected) {
        ToastAndroid.show("Connection Is Live!", ToastAndroid.LONG);
        this.setState({
            netConnection: isConnected
        });
    } else {
        ToastAndroid.show("Connection TimeOut!", ToastAndroid.LONG);
        this.setState({
            netConnection: isConnected
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried on a real device?

Comment: @PaoloDell'Aguzzo yes, same problem

Comment: Could you provide us some code? So we can see where you use NetInfo inside your code.

Comment: @PaoloDell'Aguzzo added

Comment: Have you tried to log the listener activity? When is it called? isConnected change value or is it called always with the same value? Probably they have a different behaviour and you need to check if isConnected is different from state.netConnection.
But in my apps I can see that I don't have this kind of problem. What version of RN are u using?

Comment: Check this @DeepakVerma ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198978/how-to-check-net-info-in-react-native-ios )

Comment: @PaoloDell'Aguzzo isConnected is returning false even when the device is online. using RN version 0.55.4

Comment: like @SaravanaKumar says probably you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198978/how-to-check-net-info-in-react-native-ios